# How do i fix the "Unclaimed breakpoint" error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hi i have my program below but it's showing the following error which is causing it not to run, I'm new to Qt:

> C:\Users\panas\OneDrive\Desktop\Lessons\Ass1Question1\SentenceProcessor\main.cpp:66: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
> ..\SentenceProcessor\main.cpp: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
> ..\SentenceProcessor\main.cpp:66:9: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
> 66 |         }while(!validateInput(input.at(0)));
> |

**Here is the code snippet where the error is coming from:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    int answer = 0;
    QStringList input;

    do {
        do {
            input = getSentence();
            if (input.at(1) == "cancel")
        } while (!validateInput(input.at(0)));

        QString result = generateOutput(input.at(0));
        displayOutput(result);
        answer = tryAgain();

    } while (answer == QMessageBox::Yes);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the body of your `if` statement `if(input.at(1)=="cancel")`

Comment: Your conditional `if(input.at(1)=="cancel")` doesn't have any body.  What's supposed to happen if `if(input.at(1)=="cancel")` is`true`?

Comment: Here is a free C++ tip: indent your code correctly. Make it an habit, then a strict rule. Bad indent makes code harder to understant/debug, hence your issue.